# How can I declare a struct array with the size 2^18

Tags: c, arrays, size, limit

This is my struct

```
struct Entry {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {

    struct Entry data[260000]; //ok
    struct Entry data[262144]; //crash

    return 0;
}
```

I want to declare an array of Entry with the size is 2^18 (262144 elements) But I'm not able to do so. It seems like I go beyond the max. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: this does not crash on 64-bit linux.

Comment: @Jasen it crashed on Windows 10 64bit. I'm not sure it is related to OS or IDE or something else though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not ehough room in the `auto` context (on the stack) for that array, 
declare it static or as a global, or allocate it dynamically.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: ... or increase the stacksize. linker options.